# Creating a linq condition using a list

Tags: c#, list, linq, where-clause

I have a method which used for getting a list from the database.

```
public List<SelectedCustomers> GetCustomers(List<int> customerNumbers)
{
   var customers=_context.Customers.Where(?).Select(i=> new SelectedCustomers() {}).ToList()
}
```

I want to retrieve information from the database of customers whose customer number is given by the user. There are about one hundred thousand customers in the customer list in the database. I do not want the method to take the whole list and search it every time it is called, it takes too much effort. However, I don't know how to use a list in where ().

In summary, instead of pulling out all the list I want and searching the values requested by the user in the list, I want to go to the database with the list that comes directly from the user and give me the information of these customers.

I hope I could explain. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `.Where(customer=>customerNumber.Contains(customer.ID))` generates `WHERE customer.ID in (1,4,5,8,9,....)`.

Comment: Do you mean something like: `Where(customer => customerNumbers.Contains(customer.Number))`? (After renaming your `customerNumber` to `customerNumbers` for clarity, of course.)

Comment: yes, @JonSkeet there is more than one customer number in the `customerNumber` so I am editing the name as `customerNumbers`. thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var customers = _context.Customers.Where(c => customerNumber.Contains(c.CustomerId)).Select(i => new SelectedCustomers() { }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like (not tested)

```
public List<SelectedCustomers> GetCustomers(List<int> customerNumbers)
{
   var customers=_context.Customers.Where(x =customerNumbers.Contains(x.customerNumber)
                       .Select(i=> new SelectedCustomers() {}).ToList()
}
```

This is the equivalent of the SQL `IN ()`